# Read images from website using Imagero Java library

Tags: java, jsp, image-processing

From the tutorial and information that I have seen so far, Imagero can only read image from a directory. Anyone uses Imagero lib before and knows if it can read image directly from an url?

Also, I am trying to perform image processing such as darken/brighten an image in a jsp page. Can imagero achieves that for me?

I am stuck and need some advises.

Imagero: http://reader.imagero.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an external library for downloading an image from a URL; just treat it as if you were downloading any other file. Luckily the ImageIO class provides a method called `read(URL)` which can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29) which is used for specifically for downloading images.

As far as modifying the `BufferedImage`, I would suggest looping through the width and height (representing the x and y) and get the RGB of each pixel at row,column using [`BufferedImage#getRGB(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29) and modify the color and set the color at that location using [`BufferedImage#setRGB(int, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

There are 2 different ways I could think of darkening an image: one way being to loop through each x,y and darken each individual color and the other way being to essentially draw a translucent screen over the image, both methods will be shown below:

```
public void darken(final BufferedImage image){
    for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
            image.setRGB(x, y, new Color(image.getRGB(x, y)).darker().getRGB());
}

public void darken(final BufferedImage image, final int intensity){
    assert intensity >= 0 && intensity <= 255;
    final Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, intensity));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    g.dispose();
}
```

Note about the second method: the higher the intensity = the darker the image gets.

Comment: So actually I don't have to use the Imagero lib to perform the enhancement? Is there any guides that teach me for example... darken an image, what should I set for the RGB?

Comment: @user2707516 Well, to darken an image you could just get the color at x,y and invoke `darker()` on the color and set the darker color at x,y. I will provide a code sample when I have access to my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

As Josh M says, the easiest way to read an image from a URL in Java, is probably to use `ImageIO.read(url)`.

However, the "Java way" to darken or brighten an image (a `BufferedImage`), is to use `RescaleOp`. [Here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1013851&seqNum=7)´s an excellent tutorial by Chet Haase and Romain Guy.

`RescaleOp` is highly optimized, and uses native code on most platforms, so it's definitively faster than looping through each pixel in Java.